# Limit of a function with exponentiation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

In my assignment I have to calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(1+\frac {1-\cos x} {x} \right)^\frac{1}{x}$$

According to wolfram alpha, the result is $\sqrt{e} $.

However in my calculations I got a different one. Can you please let me know where did I get it wrong?

Here's my solution:

First we represent the argument differently:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left(1+\frac {1-\cos x} {x} \right)^\frac{1}{x}= \lim_{x \to 0} \left(\left(1+\frac {1-\cos x} {x} \right)^x\right)^ {\frac{1}{x}\cdot {x}} $$

Now we use the heine theorem and write the following:

$$\lim_{ n \to \infty} \left(\left(1+\frac {1-\cos n} {n} \right)^n\right)^ {\frac{1}{n}\cdot {n}} = \lim_{ n \to \infty} \left(\left(1+\frac {1}{n}-\frac{\cos n}{n} \right)^n\right)^ {\frac{1}{n}\cdot {n}}, $$ where $\frac {1}{n}-\frac{\cos n}{n} \to 0$.  Therefore $\lim_{ n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac {1}{n}-\frac{\cos n}{n} \right)^n\to e. $

Since $\frac{1} {n}\cdot n \to 1$, the whole argument approaches 
$$e^1=e$$

Where am I wrong here?

P. S. another approach to solving this is welcome. 
Thanks,

Alan

Comment: "Therefore $\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} ((1+\frac {1}{n}-\frac{\cos n}{n} )^n\to e. $" -- here. This should be "Therefore $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{ n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac {1}{n}-\frac{\cos n}{n} \right)^\frac{1}{\frac {1}{n}-\frac{\cos n}{n}}= e. $". And even before, when changing $x$ to $n$.

Comment: $(A^n)^{\frac1n*n}=A^{n*\frac1n*n}=A^n\neq A^{\frac1n}$.

Comment: Thank you! I see what was my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to take logs. If $L$ is the desired limit then we have
\begin{align}
\log L &= \log\left(\lim_{x \to 0}\left(1 + \frac{1 - \cos x}{x}\right)^{1/x}\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\log\left(1 + \frac{1 - \cos x}{x}\right)^{1/x}\text{ (by continuity of log)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}\log\left(1 + \frac{1 - \cos x}{x}\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}\log\left(1 + \frac{1 - \cos^{2} x}{x(1 + \cos x)}\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}\log\left(1 + \frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\cdot\frac{x}{(1 + \cos x)}\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}\cdot\dfrac{\log\left(1 + \dfrac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{x}{(1 + \cos x)}\right)}{\dfrac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{x}{(1 + \cos x)}}\cdot\dfrac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{x}{(1 + \cos x)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\log\left(1 + \dfrac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{x}{(1 + \cos x)}\right)}{\dfrac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{x}{(1 + \cos x)}}\cdot1\cdot\dfrac{1}{(1 + \cos x)}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\log\left(1 + \dfrac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{x}{(1 + \cos x)}\right)}{\dfrac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{x}{(1 + \cos x)}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + t)}{t}\text{ (putting }t = \dfrac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{x}{(1 + \cos x)})\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\notag
\end{align}
It is now clear that $L = e^{1/2} = \sqrt{e}$.

Comment: $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\log(1+t)}{t}=\log\lim_{t\to 0}(1+t)^{\frac{1}{t}}=\log e=1$ by continuity of log again. It's to explain the last step.

Comment: @user26486: Normally we don't need an explanation for standard limits like $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} =  \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{x} - 1}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + x)}{x} = 1$$ and $$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{n} - a^{n}}{x - a} = na^{n - 1}$$ These have to be part of a student's toolkit when he is supposed to solve usual limit problems. Each of these limits has a proof and the ones for $\log$ and $e$ are difficult and may be avoided when presenting them to a student learning limits.

Comment: I wasn't claiming you should've provided an explanation. It's just so elementary that I provided it. $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ can be proved by: let $u=e^x-1$. Then $x=\log (1+u)$ and $x\to 0\iff u\to 0$, so the limit is equal to $\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{u}{\log (1+u)}$, which is $1$, using my last proved limit. The proof of $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, however, would normally need geometry and would take a bit of time to prove. The limit $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}$ is the derivative of $x^n$ at $a$ and I suppose you would normally know basic derivative rules before using it.

Comment: @user26486: As I mentioned the proofs for limits involving $e$ and $\log $ are difficult (definitely not as easy as you have given in comments) and depend on a theory of exponential and logarithmic functions. See my posts starting from http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-1.html That's why it is best to avoid any proofs for them for a beginner.

Comment: I assume you defined $e$ by $\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x}$. Then my proofs only used this definition and some of the techniques already used in your answer, such as continuity letting us swap function with the limit and knowing $\log(a^b)=b\log(a)$ when $a>0$. Also the simple $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{\lim_{x\to a}f(x)}$.

Comment: @user26486: The problem with your definition of $e$ is that it is too complicated and needs a full development of theory of exponential and logarithmic function. A simpler definition is $e = \lim_{n \to \infty}(1 + (1/n))^{n}$ but this will not help here as it involves an integer variable $n$ and we need a real variable $x$.

Comment: $$\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor +1}\right)^{\lfloor x \rfloor +1}\right)^{1-\frac{1}{ \lfloor x\rfloor +1}}<\left(1+ \frac{1}{x}\right)^x< \left(\left(1+\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor} \right)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor}}$$

$\lfloor x\rfloor +1\to\infty\iff x\to \infty$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor \to\infty \iff x\to \infty$, so taking $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ of all sides (and using Squeeze theorem) extends your natural number limit to the positive real numbers. I'm assuming by $n\to \infty$ you mean $n\to +\infty$.

Comment: I don't want to take this further. But the concept of an irrational exponent can't be taken for granted without reasonable amount of analytical considerations. If we are ready to take an expression like $a^{b}$ as granted when $b$ might be irrational, then it is better to take the standard limits also as granted rather than trying to prove them. Any systematic proof of such limits has to be given via a proper theory. Its not a matter of algebraic manipulations like you have done. It is best that you read my posts which I referred earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$A=\Big(1+\frac {1-\cos (x)} {x} \Big)^\frac{1}{x}$$ $$\log(A)=\frac{1}{x}\log\Big(1+\frac {1-\cos(x)} {x} \Big)$$ Now, use Taylor series $$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^5\right)$$ $$1+\frac {1-\cos(x)} {x} =1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^3}{24}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Now, use the following series $$\log(1+y)=y-\frac{y^2}{2}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ and replace $y$ by $(\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^3}{24})$ keeping the low order terms; this makes $$\log\Big(1+\frac {1-\cos(x)} {x} \Big)=\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ $$\log(A)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{8}+\cdots$$

This shows the limit and also how it is approached.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 1):

Use Asymptotic analysis: as $\cos x=1-\dfrac{x^2}2+o(x^2)$, we have:
\begin{align*}\ln\Bigl(1+\frac {1-\cos x} {x} \Bigr)^\tfrac{1}{x}&=\frac{1}{x}\ln\Bigl(1+\frac {1-\cos x} {x} \Bigr)\\
&=\frac{1}{x}\ln\Bigl(1+\frac x2 +o(x) \Bigr)=\frac{1}{x}\Bigl(\frac x2 +o(x)\Bigr)\\
&=\frac 12 +o(1),
\end{align*}
which tends to $\dfrac12$ as $x$ tends to $0$, hence the initial expression tends to $\,\mathrm e^{\tfrac12}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x}\right)^{1/x}
&=\left(1+\frac{2\sin^2(x/2)}{x}\right)^{1/x}\\
&=\left(1+\frac12\frac{\sin^2(x/2)}{(x/2)^2}x\right)^{1/x}\\
\end{align}
$$
Since $e^x$ is continuous at $x=\frac12$,
$$
\lim_{x\to0}(1+ax)^{1/x}=e^{a/2}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1
$$
we get
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\left(1+\frac12\frac{\sin^2(x/2)}{(x/2)^2}x\right)^{1/x}=e^{1/2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$(1-\cos x)/x^2 \to 1/2\implies 1-\cos x= x^2/2 +o(x^2).$ Thus the expression equals

$$(1+x/2+o(x))^{1/x} = \left [(1+x/2+o(x))^{1/(x/2+o(x))}\right ]^{(x/2+o(x))/x} $$

Using $\lim_{u\to 0}(1+u)^{1/u}=e,$ we see the limit equals $e^{1/2}.$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using L'Hôpital's rule.

$$\begin{array}{lll}
\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \left(1+\frac {1-\cos x} {x} \right)^\frac{1}{x}&=&\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \left(1+\frac {1-\cos x} {x} \right)^{\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{x}{1-\cos x}\cdot\frac{1-\cos x}{x}}\\
&=&\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \bigg[\left(1+\frac {1-\cos x} {x} \right)^{\frac{x}{1-\cos x}}\bigg]^{\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}}\\
&=& \displaystyle e^{\lim_{x \to 0}\displaystyle\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}}\\
&=& \displaystyle e^{\lim_{x \to 0}\displaystyle\frac{\sin x}{2x}}\\
&=& \displaystyle e^{\lim_{x \to 0}\displaystyle\frac{\cos x}{2}}\\
&=& \displaystyle \sqrt{e}^{\lim_{x \to 0}\displaystyle \cos x}=\sqrt{e}^1=\sqrt{e}\\
\end{array}$$